# get ip address from client in server

Tags: c#

I am using C# Framework 4.0 Windows Form. My program is installed on a server. There are 4 light clients that connect to this server.

When one of these clients launches my progam, how can I get his Ip Addreess and Computer Name

Comment: The IP address is in the endpoint property. I think it is in the Listener.Client object.  The Computer Name you probably have to ping the IP address to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net; //Include this namespace

string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST
        Console.WriteLine(hostName);
        // Get the IP
        string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

For more details visit this please:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/167ad2/get-ip-address-using-C-Sharp-code/

Thanks

Comment: I  using RDP to connect to a terminal server. i will get the IP of the terminal server, not the IP of the connected user.